# Adding aliyah breaks at the beginning of the parsha

Tags: torah-reading

Last year I was the baal korei at an aufruf.  The shul's policy was to allow two extra aliyos for a simcha, for a total of 9 + maftir.

The bride's grandfather z"l, a Kohen and Holocaust survivor in his nineties, was the first oleh.  Because he had trouble standing, I suggested to the gabbai that we add the two extra aliyah breaks at the beginning of the parsha so that he could go sit down sooner.  The gabbai responded that no, you're only allowed to add aliyah breaks at the end of the parsha.

I've never heard anything like this.  Was he correct?  Is there a source for what he said?

There was plenty of room in rishon to add aliyah breaks.  The parsha also wasn't Mas'ei or [Ki Tisa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81083), where there are specific reasons to have a long rishon.

---

*The grandfather passed away this week.  This question is dedicated lezeicher nishmaso.*

Comment: You're still adding at the end. You're just using a different set of 7 than is printed in a particular Chumash. (It so happens the 7 you are using are relatively front heavy and the two extra you are adding happen to match with two of the 7 that were printed in some Chumash, but so what.)

Comment: You might be able to bring a proof from the Rivash quoted in the Beis Yosef (OC 282), since by Chanukah and Sukkos the repeated aliyos are only at the end, but I’m not positive. Can’t find the Mordechai he quotes either, if someone wants to look into it.

Comment: @DoubleAA There could be a nafka minah when you get into extra aliyos which repeat earlier ones

Comment: @DonielF it's not a question where the extras are. You don't call up Kohein, Hosafa, Levi, Hosafa, Yisrael.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's what I thought.  That's why, except in the first paragraph, I said "extra aliyah breaks", not "extra aliyos".  The "extra breaks" are in addition to the ones in a standard Chumash.  I'm trying to understand what the gabbai was thinking.

Comment: I wonder if this whole incident was just a miscommunication between the OP and the gabbai - the former suggested having him sit down “early,” and the gabbai said no, we don’t call up hosafos before Levi.

Comment: I am pretty sure the Steipler's aliyah which was the 3rd was shortened so he can sit,check Orchos Rabbeinu

Comment: @DonielF you might be right.  I don't remember the exact words we used anymore.  In the end there was no harm done, he did ok standing.  Next time I'll speak more clearly :)

Comment: There is a minimum of 3 pasukim.  The whole reason we call up Kohein, Levi and then Yisrael is precisely to avoid fights, We don't like to shorten their aliyos, because that will cause unnecessary fights.  That could be a reason.  But as long as you don't read less than the minimum and you break at a logical point in the aliyos there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @DonielF, try Mordechai Megillah 431

Comment: @MDjava He only starts in 774?

Comment: Sorry, add a Taf. 831.  ואין נכון בעיני הך כפילות וכן כתב רבינו אפרים לרבינו יואל הנה בשמחת תורה יצאתי מבית הכנסת בחרי אף כי שמעתי (לבלע) זה החזן מדלג יותר מעשרה פעמים ו' פסוקים ומי התיר לו לדלג ולא אמר ולדן אמר ולגד אמר ולאשר אמר ורב ושמואל נחלקו בדילוג גבי ראש חודש ובדוחק התירו לו דלא אפשר:

Answer (score 6):

In Orchos Rabbeinu Chelek 1, pg.121 (in the new edition on Otzar Hachochma, pg.227), 89 and 90 it's noted that the Steipler would get the third aliyah,but due to his weakness he did not do a full aliyah.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MeIkar HaDin, both Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 282:1-2) and Rama agree one can add Aliyot either by subdividing at any point or repeating pesukim on Shabbat and Yom Tov. The Rama is machmir lechatechilah not to, though, unless there's a need and on Simchat Torah.

The poskim (see Be'er Heitev ad loc. for example) discuss various Minhagim in limiting this rule. Your Gabbai's instruction is what the Ben Ish Chai records as Minhag Baghdad (Rav Pealim vol. 3 Orach Chaim 15).

For extended discussion, see Shu"t Kol Eliyahu (Yisrael, vol 2 Orach Chaim Siman 14), Yabia Omer (vol. 9 Orach Chaim Siman 27), and Chazon Ovadia (Shabbat II page 230).
תנצב"ה.

Comment: I looked at Rav Pealim, but I don't see what you claim he says.  He says that when you add aliyos you should start and end with something good even if that means repeating pesukim, but that wasn't the issue here.

Comment: מה שנוהגין פה. עירינו בג'דאד יע"א שלא לקרות בס"ת לאחד מה שקרא לעולה שעלה לס"ת קודם ממנו כי אם רק אחר שעולים שבעה חובת היום
It's the first line.

Comment: No.  He's saying that an oleh shouldn't *repeat* any pesukim that the previous oleh read until after there have been 7 aliyos, not that you can't add additional breaks without repeating pesukim.

Comment: Good point. I have to think about it more.