Procedure for repeating aliyot on shabbat
I heard that if there are more than seven people who require an Aliyah on shabbat, one may add an additional Aliyah to the reading. What is the correct procedure for doing so? Should one repeat the same Aliyah? or split an Aliyah into multiple? If so how long must each Aliyah be?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97269/6592

Every reader must read at least three verses (OC 137:2)
No break may be within three verses of a written paragraph break, unless at a written paragraph break itself (138:1).
Some allow extra breaks beyond the minimum to be added on holidays other than Shabbat (282:1, 135:1). (Some refrain from adding on Yom Kippur even when it falls on Shabbat (Aruch HaShulchan 282:7).)
Some permit rereading verses that were already read (282:2).
Breaks should ideally be at positive thematic points (138:1).
No break may be made in Curses section of Leviticus (26:14-46), and customarily that prohibition is observed in the Curses section of Deuteronomy (28:15-69) as well (428:6).
The final 8 verses in the Torah (Deuteronomy 34:5-12) should not be split up (428:7).
The Haazinu song may only be split at the six traditional break points that were used in the Temple (428:5).
Some customarily do not split up the Song of the Sea or either record of the Decalogue (eg. Eliya Rabba 143:6).
Some customarily do not split up the list of 42 travel stations in Numbers 33 (Magen Avraham 428:5).
When a double parsha is read, some recommend all breaks be split evenly between the two while most recommend all extra breaks be added to the second parsha (Aruch HaShulchan 282:12).
