# Torah Reading for Chet Haegel, when the reader is a Levi

Tags: torah-reading, levites-leviyim, golden-calf-egel

The [Be'er Heitev in OH 428(7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.428.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) brings the custom to arrange the aliyos in Parshas Ki Sisa so that the story of the Cheit Haegel is read during the Levi aliyah.

> גם נוהגין לקרות ללוי פ' העגל וקורין אותה בקול נמוך עכ''ל

The result is that the aliyos are hugely skewed to the first two, which end up being like two-thirds of the parsha.
I seem to recall that in Rav Feivel Cohen's kehillah a"h, the baal korei himself was a Levi, and they announced that for that reason they weren't going to do it that way. Some source was given which I don't remember. Has anyone seen a source for that?

Comment: I don't know why it matters who the Baal Kriya is, but if you happen to have no leviim etc. the old breaks are https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81083/759

Comment: Why would the Baal Koreh being a Levi make a difference? Do you mean that he would be given that Aliyah as well?

Comment: @sabbahillel No, he could not be given that aliyah (or aliyos, if they are broken into several - see DbAA's list above), since he's a Levi and those are later. But as for why it makes a difference, I had a fuzzy picture that it's similar to the usual case where the ba'al korei is not a Levi and the oleh is. Gotta have a Levi there. - But a source is needed.